# Android - HttpResponseException

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app using mysql database as my back end. I access my database through php scripts. My code works perfectly but today when I try to run my app it shows an error message:

> org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: (The specified network name is no longer available)

I've searched the internet and found nothing. What would be the cause? I need help. Thanks.

**EDIT**

> 11-08 07:38:10.550: W/System.err(2788): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: ( The specified network name is no longer available.  )
>   11-08 07:38:10.590: W/System.err(2788):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
>   11-08 07:38:10.620: W/System.err(2788):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
>   11-08 07:38:10.620: W/System.err(2788):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
>   11-08 07:38:10.660: W/System.err(2788):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
>   11-08 07:38:10.660: W/System.err(2788):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
>   11-08 07:38:10.660: W/System.err(2788):     at com.example.appointmentsystem.SigninActivity$3.run(SigninActivity.java:169)

This is the logcat.

Comment: Is there any kind of firewall or some other network-level barrier?

Comment: None. Yesterday its working. I haven't change my code.

Comment: It may be because of it will take more time to connect to your server or your server not available. You checked by yesterday that is  fine.Did you check the connection by today?

Comment: The connection today is fine except when I'm trying to connect from my android app

Comment: Is your phone internet connection working?

Comment: Yes. I have used the emulator's browser to navigate to other websites and it loads the websites. Actually, the code is working since yesterday, I just don't why now its throwing an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error may be coming from your server. The server is encountering an error when it gets it. You will need to debug the web application to figure out what is wrong.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I also think that the error may be coming from the server. But I tried all my php scripts in the browser and it works. I also test the connection if its fine, and its fine. I'll post my logcat.